# Getting None as output while reading the frames of a video using cv2.VideoCapture.read()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to read all the frames of a video in Opencv, but after a certain point it is giving me "None" as a result, due to which I am not able to perform the processing tasks which I plan to do.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Create our body classifier
body_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('dataset/haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
# Initiate video capture for video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('dataset/ped.mp4')
# Loop once video is successfully loaded
while (cap.isOpened()):
    time.sleep(0.05)
    
    # Read first frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

The error which I am getting is here below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceRfH.jpg)

Some points I would like to clarify before is that:
The path for the video mentioned is correct and also I have tried a
changing the "time.sleep" and the speed of the video but nothing worked and got the same error again.

Can anyone please tell what is the reason behind the "None" value and how could this be resolved.

I am adding the link of the video below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HtNrm5rI9rtMJRqoSrqc5d1EFmTX5IXS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I downloaded the video, and I can't see any issues. Instead of `print(frame)`, use `cv2.imshow('frame', frame)` and `cv2.waitKey(40)` for visualizing the video. You can count the frames. My count is 386 frames. The video is 15 seconds at 25fps, it should be about `15*25` = `375` frames (so 386 is OK). You are getting `null` at the last frame. You need to break the loop if `ret` is not `True`.

Comment: @Rotem  Thanx it worked ! just a query ..on what basis you used cv2.waitKey as "40" ??

Comment: The video framerate is 25fps. 1sec/25 = 0.04sec = 40msec. It's not an accurate playback, because `cap.read()` and `cv2.imshow('frame', frame)` also takes time.